Unable to format date axes on excel
I have various dates from 1995 to now in my excel database, I am trying to count no of entries for each date and plot the date(x-axis) vs count(y-axis) plot
So first I create a pivot on date column and then create a table of date vs count and then plot it,
I want to show x axis at 2 year interval and not individual date type, but when I click on format axes it doesn't allow to change intervals or view bounds
Here is what I am currently plotting and this is what I want  

So make a separate x axis column with just the years and use that.

@Excellor when I choose only years in pivot table and plot a line graph it does not show the changes within that particular year , it just connect the sum of all years and make a plot but I want to show the fluctuations within the years as well as shown in desired plot

In my version of Excel 365, it seems that a line chart derived from a Pivot Table does not have the options to set the bounds or units on the horizontal axis, and also that setting the Number format on this dialog has no effect.
A possible workaround is to select those two columns from the Pivot Table output, then copy => paste special => numbers and value formats to some other area.Ensure that you do not include Totals or Subtotals.
If you then create a line chart from that copied value, you should see the appropriate options from the Format Axis dialog:

The latter allows you to set the bounds and intervals using dates.

yeah this was the exact issue
